# Can someone explain the bytecode modification performed to prevent this bytecode from being directly decompiled?

Tags: java, obfuscation, bytecode

Can anyone explain to me what bytecode modification was performed on the following bytecode to prevent it from being decompiled into valid java source code?

```
0: aload_0
1: invokevirtual 102    java/lang/String:toCharArray    ()[C
4: dup
5: arraylength
6: iconst_2
7: if_icmpge +12 -> 19
10: dup
11: iconst_0
12: dup2
13: caload
14: bipush 33
16: ixor
17: i2c
18: castore
19: areturn
```

This bytecode was removed from a class obfuscated with zkm obfuscation.

Comment: There is always the possibility that it was written directly as bytecode, not compiled from Java source (or some other JVM language) and then obfuscated...

Comment: How did you determine that it can't be decompiled into valid Java source code? And how do you know that that's a result of obfuscation with that purpose?

Comment: Which decompiler are you using? There's no guarantee that any given decompiler will be able to understand all possible bytecode output from the compiler.

Comment: None of the decompilers I've tested have been able to generate a valid output for it.  And I know it was obfuscated because it's part of ZKM's String obfuscation.  And as for the main decompiler I was using, that was JD-Gui, but it wasn't the only one I used to test.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the original code was something like:

```
char[] mystery_method(String s) {
   char[] r = s.toCharArray();
   if (r.length < 2) {
       r[0] ^= 33;
   }
   return r;
}
```

I don't see anything particularly tricky about that bytecode that would cause trouble for a decompiler.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that there was some deliberate modification. I don't think there is. Perhaps your compiler is simply more clever than your decompiler.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it can *probably* be decompiled quite easily.  All that can be done is to *obfuscate* bytecode to make it harder to decompile...which only really works on code more complex than that code appears to be.

Indeed, this could probably be decompiled by hand, just by looking at it for a few minutes...

Comment: There isn't one, is the point.  There's not anything preventing direct decompiling, except possibly the fact that it's not part of a complete `.class` file.

Comment: Okay...then there's not anything preventing that class from being decompiled.  Have you _tried_ using a decompiler on it?

Comment: Can you give some more details?  What do you mean by "valid"?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, optimization phase will  prevent you from decompiling a whole .class file correctly. Well, at least making it much more complicated, because of merging of similar code paths for example. You might end up with a bunch of (pseudo) goto's, which you can't use in java.